# How long does it take to receive a provisional patent filing receipt?

Tags: provisional-application

I electronically filed my provisional patent application on December 26, 2018. When can I expect to receive my provisional patent filing receipt from the USPTO in the mail? At what point can I began to use the term "patent pending"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filing receipt in the mail on January 7. It was mailed on January 4, so it took approximately 8 days for the application to be processed, and 11 days to reach me.

Answer (score 1):

For applications filed electronically, filing acknowledgement and fee receipt is generated immediately. Option for print out is given immediately. If you have missed it than you can get the same from from EFS-Web PAIR. As about the receipt being sent by USPS mail, US residents may be getting it, but overseas inventors don't (at least for an pro se inventor from India). If you are registered e-filer, you can give email option for notification and will get notification.

For more details may look [here](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s503.html)  and
also this [link](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/ebc/portal/efs/efs_web1_2.pdf)

Comment: It is not correct that a non-registered electronic filer can see their application in PAIR shortly after filing a provisional application. Without a customer number, they would not be able to access PRIVATE PAIR. The application would not be visible in PUBLIC PAIR because applications are not made public until publication - 18 months after a non-provisional is filed. You can call up the EBC help center. If you have the date of filing, and the title, they may be able to tell you the application number.